# ORA-00918: column ambiguously defined

Tags: sql, database, oracle, view, sql-view

I'm learning SQL Oracle and tried to create a view, but I keep getting this error. I know is because of that NULL, but still don't know how to fix it. Any advice is helpful. Thanks.

```
CREATE VIEW Produse_HP (model, categorie, viteza, ram, hd, ecran, culoare, tip, pret)
AS
    SELECT * 
    FROM
        (SELECT model, categorie, viteza, ram, hd, NULL, NULL, NULL, pret
         FROM Produs 
         NATURAL JOIN PC
         WHERE fabricant = 'HP' 
         UNION
         SELECT model, categorie, viteza, ram, hd, ecran, NULL, NULL, pret
         FROM Produs 
         NATURAL JOIN Laptop
         WHERE fabricant = 'HP' 
         UNION
         SELECT model, categorie, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, culoare, tip, pret
         FROM Produs 
         NATURAL JOIN Imprimanta
         WHERE fabricant = 'HP');
```

It suppose to show those columns with `SELECT [model, categorie, viteza, ram, hd, ecran, culoare, tip, pret]`. I need it this way because I need it in a instead-of trigger, to insert values through this view.

Comment: Side notes: You should never ever use `NATURAL JOIN`. In my opinion it should have never been invented. Image someday you add a last_update column to each table for instance. Suddenly, all the queries you've run day by day won't work anymore, because the DBMS would look for matching timestamps. Then, when working with mulltiple tables, always qualify all columns with the table names. Is it `Produs.model` or `laptop.model`? Qualify the columns, so as to make the queries both more readable and less error-prone. At last: Do you really need `UNION [DISTINCT]` or would `UNION ALL` suffice?

Comment: It is from an exercise. It give this view and have to create and instead-of trigger with it.

Answer (score 0):

You need aliases for the nulls. At least in your first query, so that Oracle knows how to call the columns in the result:

```
SELECT
  model, categorie, viteza, ram, hd,
  NULL AS ecran, NULL AS culoare, NULL AS tip, pret
FROM Produs NATURAL JOIN PC
WHERE fabricant = 'HP'
UNION
...
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to @Thorsten 's answer you need to declare the datatype of your nulls using a CAST() function.  Something like,

```
CAST(Null as Varchar) as ecran, CAST(Null as Date) as culoare...
```

Comment: I know this to be necessary in some DBMS, SQL Server in particular, but I am pretty sure it is not necessary in Oracle. The DBMS sees what data types are needed from the following queries.

Comment: It was something I encountered in earlier Oracles, possibly fixed now?

Comment: I don't recall ever having problems with this in Oracle. But, anyway, it is not a problem in recent versions at least: https://dbfiddle.uk/tjIzeVnP